# Obtener datos desde ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener datos a través de ajax y php. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es tener una lista de varios id y que ajax me los muestre dinámicamente. Mi cliente quiere ver una lista de mensajes haciendo clic en cada uno, algo así como el inbox de icloud.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.enlaceajax').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'pagina-lenta.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.destino').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?=$fila['id'];?>">class="enlaceajax"></a>
<div class="destino"></div>
```

PHP:

```
$ide = $_GET['id'];

if($ide == 1) {
   echo 'Texto de ID 1';
}else {
   echo 'Error';
}
```

El error está en que no me da ningún resultado. No sé que estoy haciendo mal, espero me ayuden. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Dónde pasas el parámetro `id`? Parece que no se pasa en ninguna parte, eso generará un error PHP. ¿Has probado a poner una sección de error en la llamada AJAX para ver si devuelve algún error en particular?

Comment: Necesitas pasar al servidor el valor del `id` que quieres consultar, tomándolo de alguna parte en la página actual. El servidor buscará en una base de datos (o en otra fuente de almacenamiento) la información relativa a ese id y te la devolverá. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04) parecido, para probarlo pulsa **`Run-F9`**. Revisando el código verás que a partir de aquí `$("#btnLlenar").click(function() {` se toma un id desde la página actual y se envía al servidor para obtener los datos. El formulario se llena en base a la respuesta del servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores, te corrijo el código y te explico:

Lo primero el `HTML`, que tienes un error de sintaxis ya que cierras la etiqueta antes de añadir la clase, además no seleccionas el parámetro que enviamos por `Ajax`, yo te recomiendo agregar un parámetro data-id, que debes rellenar con la ID (`PHP`):

```
<a href="#" data-id="<?=$fila['id'];?>" class="enlaceajax">Enlace</a>
<div class="destino"></div>
```

Lo siguente, el `JS`. No recoges ni pasas el valor, además debes hacer un `preventDefault()` del evento, para que no se ejecute el enlace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.enlaceajax').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'id' : $(this).data('id')},
            url: 'pagina-lenta.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.destino').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Como ves, he añadido la detención del evento a la función click `function(e)` asignando un parámetro a la función (personalmente suelo usar una `e`) que será la que recoja el evento y lo pase a la función, y además un parámetro a la función ajax que es data, que recoge y envía los datos que nos interesa.

El `PHP` que muestras para probar es correcto, por lo que funcionará sin modificarlo.

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias jonilgz. Voy a probarlo cuando llegue. Gracias nuevamente!